# How can two apps access the microphone simultaneously?

Tags: microphone, voice-command

If an app tries to access the microphone while the microphone is already being accessed, it fails.

How can I make two or more apps access the microphone at the same moment?

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can't. because microphone just like camera is a hardware part of the phone and it's drivers connects to only one source, there is a way to make this work but it will be difficult, by using an app to transfer the audio came from microphone and stream it to another app.

Comment: But how does the telephone app do calls while a third-party voice recorder can keep recording?

Comment: . . . and how come desktop computers and laptops do not have this limitation?

Answer (score 1):

It was possible in earlier versions of Android. And I find the same problem, too. **Using the third-party apps** seems to fix this problem.

**From www.androidpolice.com;**
Privileged apps have higher priority than ordinary apps.
Apps with visible foreground UIs have higher priority than background apps.
Apps capturing audio from a privacy-sensitive source have higher priority than apps that are not.
Two ordinary apps can never capture audio at the same time.
In some situations, a privileged app can share audio input with another app.
If two background apps of same priority are capturing audio, the last one started has higher priority.

**Reference:**

1. https://www.androidpolice.com/2019/09/12/android-10-allows-multiple-apps-to-access-your-microphone-at-once/
2. https://gadgetstouse.com/blog/2020/05/06/working-trick-to-record-whatsapp-video-and-voice-calls/